# How to make input type time into intervals

Tags: jquery, input

I have a website of a restaurant that I want to make only the opening hours avaiable to choose from;
The restaurant is opened on Monday 8am->12am and 3pm->6pm

So the user can only choose during this time
It is an input in form , I have tried a lot and can not access.
I can't even find a tutorial or course to start with .

Thanks in advance

[Imprim du code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPFUx.png)

Comment: Please post your actual code. The html and jquery scripts for this particular problem.

Comment: Without more information, I don't see why a pre-defined ``<select>`` field couldn't be used that lists off each half-hour increment between 8 and 12, and 3 and 6.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GrantNoe but that is a restaurant we can't define the interval in term of half hour which means any time chosen can be token